# CATransform3DRotate rotate for 360 degrees

Tags: iphone, objective-c, calayer, catransform3d, quartz-core

I've started using CATransform3D lately and it seems very nice. I just have 1 issue with the rotation though. I'm trying to rotate my view for 360˚ degrees to the right but if I just put pass 360 to CATransform3DRotate it doesn't work (It just doesn't move at all.)

Here's my code:

```
      CALayer *layer = dock.layer;
      CATransform3D r = CATransform3DIdentity;
      r.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
      r = CATransform3DRotate(r, DegreesToRadians(360.0f), 100.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);   
      layer.transform = r;
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Are you trying to rotate 180 or 360 degrees? Because I think rotating 360 degrees is the same as not rotating at all.

Comment: @htinlinn I think he's trying to animate his layer through a full 360 degree rotation.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can animate a layer through one (or more) full rotations around its Z axis by animating the layer's `transform.rotation` key path, like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
animation.duration = .25;
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2 * M_PI];
[layer addAnimation:animation forKey:animation.keyPath];
```

You can animate around the X or Y axes using the key paths `transform.rotation.x` and `transform.rotation.y`.  (The `transform.rotation.z` key path has the same effect as the `transform.rotation` key path.)  You can apply multiple rotations, on separate axes, simultaneously.

Another way to do it, which probably works better if you want to rotate around an off-axis vector, is using a keyframe animation, like this:

```
CALayer *layer = [sender layer];
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -50;
layer.transform = transform;

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
animation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, 0 * M_PI / 2, 100, 1, 100)],
    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, 1 * M_PI / 2, 100, 1, 100)],
    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, 2 * M_PI / 2, 100, 1, 100)],
    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, 3 * M_PI / 2, 100, 1, 100)],
    [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DRotate(transform, 4 * M_PI / 2, 100, 1, 100)],
    nil];
animation.duration = 2;
[layer addAnimation:animation forKey:animation.keyPath];
```